# Setting image source dynamically using a converter- windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

Based on response from web service,I need to bind either of the two images from my local folder for which I am using a converter.

```
 public class typeconverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string text = value.ToString();

            if (text != null)
            {
                if (text == "1")
                {
                    Uri uri = new Uri("/projectname;component/Assets/call.png", UriKind.Relative);

                    return new BitmapImage(uri);
                }
                if (text == "2")
                {
                    BitmapImage imgSource = new BitmapImage(
          new Uri("/projectname;component/Assets/wtp.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

                    return imgSource;
                }

            }

            return value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value;
        }
    }
```

I have made build action for both the image as Resource.
In XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox5" Margin="0,-15,0,-36"
                    Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center" SelectionChanged="MainListBox5_SelectionChanged"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Height="120" Width="420">
                                <Grid MinWidth="420">
                                    <TextBlock FontSize="36" Text="{Binding ticket_number}" Margin="5,0,0,0" MinWidth="300" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding created_time}" Margin="0,15,0,0" MinWidth="115" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                                </Grid>
                                <Grid MinWidth="420">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="390"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding request_type_id,Converter={StaticResource typeconvert}}"></Image>
                                    <TextBlock  Text="completed" Foreground="#FF339933" Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                    </Grid>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>


<Grid.Resources>
            <local:typeconverter x:Key="typeconvert"/>
        </Grid.Resources>
```

I am unable to display the images,When I debug I can find "System.Invalid operation exception " in all the properties of imgSource.UriSource.

Comment: The xaml code you have posted is not enough to understand the issue.

Comment: @MuhammadUmar I have added the template for listbox..

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code? Setting breakpoint at Convert() and see if the values are correct?

Comment: @Romasz I tried to debug.. the values are correct,It goes through the if loop..I guess there is a problem with the image source..

Comment: Try by directly setting the path as source for `Image` and check is it displays?

Comment: What is request_type_id (a property?), Can you see any elements of your ListBox (TextBlock) if you got rid off the Image?

Comment: Is "projectname" the real name of the project that contains the images?

Comment: This solved the issue..  BitmapImage bm = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets/ask.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)); It works fine. now.. thank you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class typeconverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string text = value.ToString();

        if (text != null)
        {
            if (text == "1")
            {
               return "/Assets/call.png";                    
            }
            if (text == "2")
            {
               return "/Assets/wtp.png";                   
            }

        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value;
    }
}
```

This may solve your problem.